# About the function used in this script

Tags: php, curl

I was making a script for remote upload files to my server and here the code. BTW i took it from a site. I didn't post the site name or it might b considered as spam or something. Its about downloading remote files into our server.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['myupload']))    
{

    $links_list = $_POST['upload'];
    $incr = 0;
    $links = explode("\r\n",$links_list);

    define('BUFSIZ', 4095);

    for ( $incr == 0 ; $incr < count($links) ; $incr++ )
    {
        $url = $links[$incr];
        $rfile = fopen($url, 'r');
        $lfile = fopen(basename($url), 'wb');
        while(!feof($rfile))
            fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);
        fclose($rfile);
        fclose($lfile);
    }
}
?> 

    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>    
<body>
    <div id="upload_box">
        <form action="" method="post">   
            <textarea name="upload" cols=80 rows=20></textarea>
            <input type="submit" name="myupload" value="Upload Files">
        </form>
```

I want to ask few things about this script.

- `$lfile = fopen(basename($url), 'wb')` < what does this code do ?
- `fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);` < and what about this code ?

I know am asking a foolish question but hope you guys could shed some light on that for me.

Comment: RTFM ;) [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) as well as [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)

Comment: Notice that the "for" loop should normally *assign* $incr ($incr = 0), not *test* it ($incr == 0). The code still works because $incr is *also* zeroed a few lines above. Then, fopen ought to check for errors, to avoid crashing the script. Also, your code as it is is, well, exploitable. I could use it to have *your* server issue HTTP calls on *my* behalf *and* possibly **upload remotely executable code**. Remember not to leave it at the disposal of anonymous users.

Comment: @Iserni stop scaring me :P Jk mate and yes i know mate anybody could upload shell in my server with this upload page right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lfile = fopen(basename($url), 'wb')
```

`fopen`: Function that opens a file and returns a handle that can be used to read/write that file, depending on the second argument (explained below).

`basename`: Function that strips the path from the file name, leaving just the name part. For example: `basename('http://foo.com/bar.txt')` would return `bar.txt`

`'wb'`: This tells fopen how to open the file: `w` means open it for writing, `b` means open it for binary access, which just means don't do any funky line ending translation (only really useful on Windows).

`$lfile`: This is the handle to the file that will be used later to write to it.

```
fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);
```

`fwrite`: Writes data to a previously opened file handle (`$lfile` in this case)

`fread`: Reads data from a file.

`BUFSIZ`: I'm assuming this is a constant defined somewhere. Regardless, the 3rd parameter to 
`fwrite` specifies how many bytes to write to the file, and the 2nd parameter to `fread` specifies how many bytes to read. In this case, they are both the same.

This kind of operation is sometimes known as a buffered or block copy.

Broken apart it would look something like this:

```
$data = fread($rfile, BUFSIZ);
fwrite($lfile, $data, BUFSIZ);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You sir are a Genius. You explained things better than my professor. lol wanna teach me php sir =)) Jk. Thanks alot for such descriptive answer mate :) And yes BUFSIZ has been defined as 4095 Jus saying :D

Comment: You're absolutely welcome :) An accept would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd add that `fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);` makes little sense; the buffer returned by read will never exceed `BUFSIZ`, so it is better to write it as `fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ));`. In addition to being a bit simpler, this way, *if* the impossible happened, the extra bytes would not be lost, as they would be now.

Comment: Done. Sorry didnt knew about that green tick :P new to stackoverflow. And i can't +1 your answer as am lacking a lil bit of reputation (which is 15 BTW :p ).

Comment: Not a problem, thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

```
1st > $lfile = fopen(basename($url), 'wb') < what does this code do ?
```

This line opens the $url and returns handle for that url.

`Basename()`

> Given a string containing the path to a file or directory, this function will return the trailing name component.

```
 2nd > fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ); < and what about this code ?
```

This will write for stream `$lfile` the content of stream `$rfile` and size of reading/writing is **4095** defined `define('BUFSIZ', 4095);`

Take a look at this part

```
while(!feof($rfile))
  fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);
```

This part will read the data in portions defined by **BUFSIZ** until the character "end of file" `feof()` function.

So your code will download the links that are posted in form. That's all what it does.

Answer (score 0):

`$lfile = fopen(basename($url), 'wb')`

creates a file pointer to write binary file using the last segment of the url provided (which is usually the filename) and returns the file pointer/handler to the variable named $lfile

`fwrite($lfile, fread($rfile, BUFSIZ), BUFSIZ);`

reads BUFSIZ long bytes from file pointer/handler $rfile and push to to be written to the file pointed by $lfile. Writes also BUFSIZ amoung of bytes